# iframe from my website not loading

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to load a page from my [website](http://www.karmielfolkklub.com/) into an iframe in another page, which I'm currently running on localhost. Unfortunately, it's not working. I've tried loading other pages from youtube, heroku (where my page is hosted) etc. and they all work fine, it's only content specifically from my website that's not loaded. Any ideas why?

The code for my page is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">            
  </head>   
  <body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.karmielfolkklub.com"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats a sample "src" of the file/resource you are trying to include?  the URL in your code?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understood your question but if you mean what am I trying to show, then yes it's the content in the src URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page http://www.karmielfolkklub.com is sent with HTTP headers that say:

```
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
```

[This means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) that browsers are not allowed to display the page in an inline frame, unless the page containing the iframe element is in the same domain. Modern browsers generally obey this.

Changing this depends on the server settings or on the server-side code used to generate the page.

Comment: Thanks. Just for anyone looking at this in the future: this is a Sinatra app. To enable iframe embedding do `set :protection, :except => :frame_options`.